# Go templates: How do I access array item (arr[2]) in templates?

Tags: templates, go, beego

How do I access an array item (e.g. a[2]) in templates?

Whenever I do this I get "bad character U+005B '['"

```
{{ .a[2] }}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

to access a field on an array item as go templating in *.yaml format :

```
{{ (index .Values.fields 0).fieldItem }}
```

Index of zero(0) as in fields array of field as fieldItem .

Answer (score 168):

You need to use the `index` template function.

```
{{index .a 2}}
```

Comment: To access a field on an array item use `{{ (index .a 2).field }}`.

Comment: @webwurst what if field is an variable? `.$field` doesn't work

Comment: @TomSawyer Wrap it in another index `{{ index (index .a 2) $field }}`