# How do I access substrings (s[:2]) in Go templates?

Tags: string, go, go-templates

Similar to [Go templates: How do I access array item (arr[2]) in templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235211/)
How do I directly access substrings (e.g. s[:2]) in Go templates?

Whenever I do this I get "bad character U+005B '['"

```
{{ .s[:2] }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the `slice` template function on `string`s too (it was added in [Go 1.13](https://go.dev/doc/go1.13)):

[Template functions:](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Functions)

> ```
> slice
>   slice returns the result of slicing its first argument by the
>   remaining arguments. Thus "slice x 1 2" is, in Go syntax, x[1:2],
>   while "slice x" is x[:], "slice x 1" is x[1:], and "slice x 1 2 3"
>   is x[1:2:3]. The first argument must be a string, slice, or array.
> ```

For example:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`{{ slice . 0 2 }}`))
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, "abcdef"); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/f6lvc-cPROR)):

```
ab
```

Don't forget that Go strings store the UTF-8 encoded byte sequence, and indexing and slicing strings uses the byte index (not the `rune` index). This matters when the string contains multi-byte runes, like in this example:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`{{ slice . 0 3 }}`))
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, "世界"); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

This will output a single `rune` (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/gFUtEYawRZ-)):

```
世
```